# Callback from unmanaged C++ to C# works, but only in debugger

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Callbacks to C# from unmanaged C++ are tricky.
I learned most of the required cruft from this
[MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367eeye0%28VS.80%29.aspx)
and this 
    [stackoverflow tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681930/what-is-the-difference-between-a-delegate-instance-and-a-method-pointer),
and the result works fine in the debugger. 
But outside of the debugger it fails with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Here's the (simplified) C# code:

```cs
class CSharpCode
{
    delegate void CallbackDelegate();

    void DoCSharp()
    {
        CallbackDelegate callbackDelegate = TheCallback;
        IntPtr callbackDelegatePointer = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callbackDelegate);
        GCHandle gchCallbackDelegate = GCHandle.Alloc(callbackDelegatePointer);

        GC.Collect(); // create max space for unmanaged allocations
        CppCliCode.DoCppCli(callbackDelegatePointer);
    }

    public static void TheCallback()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It worked");
    }
}
```

And here's the C++ code:

```cpp
#pragma managed

public ref class CppCliCode
{
    static void DoCppCli(IntPtr^ callbackDelegatePointer)
    {
        callback theCallback = static_cast<callback>(callbackDelegatePointer->ToPointer());
        DoCpp(theCallback);
    }
}

#pragma unmanaged

typedef void (__stdcall *callback)();

void DoCpp(callback theCallback)
{
    theCallback();
}
```

The error occurs somewhere between invoking `theCallback()` and arriving at `TheCallback()`. The error suggests that some invisible managed object has become `null`.

If I remove the GC.Collect() the problem goes away. But that just means it will reappear someday as an intermittent mystery when a GC happens to occur at the wrong moment.

The GCHandle protects the delegate from being collected but allows it to be relocated. The MSDN article says "If a delegate is re-located by a garbage collection, it will not affect the underlaying managed callback, so Alloc is used to add a reference to the delegate, allowing relocation of the delegate, but preventing disposal. Using GCHandle instead of pin_ptr reduces fragmentation potential of the managed heap."

What's wrong?

Comment: Possibly your code violates this rule: You must manually keep the delegate from being collected by the garbage collector from managed code (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate.aspx). Try to define callbackDelegate variable in C# as class member.

Comment: The GCHandle keeps the wrong object alive.  You'd have a leak if you do it right.  Instead add GC.KeepAlive(callbackDelegate) at the *end* of the method.  Same thing the debugger does.

Comment: @HansPassant why didn't you post this as an answer?

Comment: Because explaining how to do it properly is a lot more work.  Don't have the time right now.

Comment: GC.KeepAlive(callbackDelegate) does fix the problem! If @HansPassant wants to post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must allocate the delegate itself, not its `IntPtr`. Also you must free the `GCHandle` when you are done with `CSharpCode` instance.

```
class CSharpCode : IDisposible
{
    delegate void CallbackDelegate();
    GCHandle gchCallbackDelegate;

    void DoCSharp()
    {
        CallbackDelegate callbackDelegate = TheCallback;
        IntPtr callbackDelegatePointer = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callbackDelegate);
        gchCallbackDelegate = GCHandle.Alloc(callbackDelegate); // !!!!

        GC.Collect(); // create max space for unmanaged allocations
        CppCliCode.DoCppCli(callbackDelegatePointer);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        CleanUp();
    }

    ~CSharpCode()
    {
        CleanUp();
    } 

    CleanUp()
    {
        if(gchCallbackDelegate.IsAllocated)
            gchCallbackDelegate.Free();
    }


}
```

By the way I hope you have more powerful naming system of yours. Names like `DoCSharp`, `TheCallBack`, `theCallBack` etc. gave me a hard time to understand the question.

Comment: Thanks for spotting my error, hanging onto the delegate does in fact work. Sorry the naming was confusing.

Comment: Thanks for this simple example.  It cleared up a couple questions I had and was very helpful!